# Facebook API Access token

Tags: php, facebook, api

Hello I am reading the Facebook API docs but I need a simple Help.

```
$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
       . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
       . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;
```

I do understand all the variables...

But I do NOT understand what is `$code`

What is that variable?

I just need to get the last status of the user from the Facebook Feed.

I need to generate the Access Token, but I do not really know what that $code means??

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explained thoroughly in Facebook Developers Documentation [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).

> If the user presses Allow, your app is
>   authorized. The OAuth Dialog will
>   redirect (via HTTP 302) the user's
>   browser to the URL you passed in the
>   redirect_uri parameter with an
>   authorization code:
>
> `http://YOUR_URL?code=A_CODE_GENERATED_BY_SERVER`

After you recieve this code you can use it to get an access token:

> In order to authenticate your app, you
>   must pass the authorization code and
>   your app secret to the Graph API token
>   endpoint at
>   https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token.
>   The app secret is available from the
>   Developer App and should not be shared
>   with anyone or embedded in any code
>   that you will distribute (you should
>   use the client-side flow for these
>   scenarios).

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
      client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&
      client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&code=THE_CODE_FROM_ABOVE
```

Comment: I am using offline permissions. And I am using the javascript library. How do I get that using the javascript library. This is driving me crazy

Answer (score 0):

there is a better way .

goto `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/`
and generate a new access token after selecting the scope
and then when you hit any API in place of code , use access_token=<%new generated token %>,
you can extend that token validity to 3 months as well. 
so you dont need to hit

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
```

again and again.
maybe you need to call loginFB() that automatically gets the token.
hope this helps